# Can not show detail about user (codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

my code can not show detail about one user that i choose, it just always shows the detail about the last user on the table no matter who i am click on.
I think my problem is my code can not realize who did i click on so it just choose the last user. Can you have look and help me solve my problem.
This is my view (i am using modal on bootstrap modal to show the result)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="userDetail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_open('admin/update_event'); ?>
        <p><b>User Name</b></p><p><input class = "form-control" placeholder = "User name" type='text' 
        name = 'event_name' id = 'event_name' readonly value = "<?php echo $r->username;?>"></p>

        <p><b>Email</b></p><p><input class = "form-control" readonly placeholder = "Email" type='text' 
        name = 'event_code' id = 'event_code' readonly value = "<?php echo $r->email;?>"></p>
        <hr>
        <p><b>First Name</b></p><p><input class = "form-control" readonly placeholder="First Name of member" type='text' 
        name = 'event_size' id = 'event_size' readonly value = "<?php echo $r->firstname;?>"></p>

        <p><b>Last Name</b></p><p><input class = "form-control" readonly placeholder="Last Name" type='text' 
        name = 'lastname' readonly value = "<?php echo $r->lastname;?>"></p>

        <p><b>Level</b></p><p>
        <select class = "form-control">
            <option selected disabled><?php if($r->level==1){
                    echo 'Admin';
                }else{
                    echo 'Member';
                } ?></option>
            <option value="1" <?php echo ($r->level == 1)?:""; ?>>Administrator</option>
            <option value="0" <?php echo ($r->level == 2)?:""; ?>>Member</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p><b>Status</b></p><p><select class = "form-control">
            <option selected disabled><?php if($r->sta==1){
                    echo 'Deactive';
                }else{
                    echo 'Active';
                } ?></option>
            <option value="1" <?php echo ($r->sta == 1)?:""; ?>>Deactive</option>
            <option value="0" <?php echo ($r->level == 0)?:""; ?>>Active</option>
        </select></p>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Update" class = "btn btn-primary">
    <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

and this is my code:

```
   <?php 
$count = 1;

foreach ($ro as $r) 
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $count++?></td>

        <td>
            <a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDetail">
                <?php echo $r->username; ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $r->email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->firstname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->lastname; ?></td>
        <td><?php $r->level; 
            if($r->level==1){
                echo '<strong><p style="color:#0047b3;">Admin</p></strong>';
            }else{
             echo '<strong><p style="color:#993300;">Member</p></strong>';
         }
         ?></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
 }
 ?>
```

This is my controller

```
function admins_area(){
    $data['main_content'] = 'backend/home/admins_area';
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $data['rows']= $this->membership_model->getUserData();
    $data['ro']= $this->membership_model->getAllUserData();
    $this->load->view('includes/admin/template', $data);
}
```

And this is my model

```
function getUserData(){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
function getAllUserData(){
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Create a file named Modal.php in your controller and paste this code in this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Modal extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();        
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        /*cache control*/
        $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
        $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
        $this->output->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
    }

    /***default functin, redirects to login page if no admin logged in yet***/
    public function index()
    {

    }


    /*
    *   $page_name      =   The name of page
    */
    function popup($page_name = '' , $param2 = '' , $param3 = '')
    {
        //$account_type             =   $this->session->userdata('login_type');
        $page_data['param2']        =   $param2;
        $page_data['param3']        =   $param3;
        $this->load->view( $page_name.'.php' ,$page_data);
    }
}
```

and 
this to see all users

```
<?php 
$count = 1;

foreach ($ro as $r) 
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $count++?></td>

        <td>
                <?php echo $r->username; ?>
        </td>
<td>
<button onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo site_url(); ?>/modal/popup/details/<?php echo $r->username; ?>')">Details</button>
</td>
</tr><?php } ?>
```

And some html

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_ajax" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog" >
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">User Details</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">



                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and some javascript

```
<script>
function showAjaxModal(url)
    {
        // SHOW AJAX RESPONSE ON REQUEST SUCCESS
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(response)
            {
                jQuery('#modal_ajax .modal-body').html(response);                         
                jQuery('#modal_ajax').modal('show', {
                  backdrop: 'static',
                  keyboard: false
                });

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And finally create a file named details.php in your application/views folder and Write

```
<?php
$this->db->where('username', $param2);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

$details = $query->row();

print_r($details);
?>
```